# confused how to use opentables in yql

Tags: yql

i am trying to get access to whitepages using YQL. Unfortunately i don't have much experience with opentables.

I was directed to the whitepages xml file at: 
http://github.com/spullara/yql-tables/blob/c63212b2ac9db6feb77ae3cecace51ed52e08c01/whitepages/whitepages.search.xml

Does anyone know how to use this table to extract meaningful information using YQL?

Specifically, I'm not sure how to make a query in YQL using this table to search for a person's name.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the YQL console http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ and click *Show Community Tables*. That should make the list on the right much bigger, and will include your table.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to put

&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env

at the end of your request?